# Xamarin spinner firing itemSelected event multiple times

Tags: java, android, xamarin, spinner, android-spinner

I am writing some code in Xamarin but I assume my issue would be similar in Java. 
In my main activity I have few spinners and I want to trigger some action when an item is changed.

Suppose the spinner holds a list of names and the action to perform when an item is selected is a toast showing the name I selected in the spinner.

When I first launch the app, the spinner is populated with some names and I put the following line to trigger the toast when an item is selected

```
spinNames.ItemSelected += SpinNames_ItemSelected;
```

and the method

```
private void SpinNams_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
{
   // toast message with the selected name
}
```

the problem is that this event is fired multiple times cause actually there is always an item selected. 
How can I make sure that the event is only fired the very first time (when the activity is launched, so the spinner is populated and shown the first time) and then only when there is a new item selected in the spinner. 
So that the event is only fired once when I actuallymake a new selection in the spinner. 
I thought I could use some global variable to store the current selection so that the firing of the event can be conditioned to the item selected in the spinner to differ from what the global variable stores. 
But seems too complex since I might have many new global variables to handle when I have multiple spinners. Any smarter way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Where do you assign the event?

Comment: It is in the onCreate of the main activity